# Can't create empty database with postgres -- permission denied when changing directory

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu, syntax

I am learning SQL, via postgres.  I understand the basic concepts of databases, but I'm having some IT trouble.  I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Go to my working directory:

```
myname@myname:~$ cd Dropbox/working_directory
```

make a new user:

```
myname@myname:~/Dropbox/working_directory$ sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive
[sudo] password for myname: 
could not change directory to "/home/myname/Dropbox/working_directory": Permission denied
Enter name of role to add: sammy
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

OK, it couldn't change the working directory, but it let me add "sammy", and set "sammy" to be a superuser.  Is this what happened?

According to the tutorial, one should make a database with the same name as the user.  This seems arbitrary.  Is that so?  Anyway, when I go and try to create a database named "sammy", I get an error that I can't change the working directory:

```
myname@myname:~/Dropbox/working_directory$ sudo -u  postgres createdb sammy
could not change directory to "/home/myname/Dropbox/working_directory": Permission denied
```

Looking in the file browser, I don't see any sign of "sammy"

**1. Why can't I change the working directory?  How do I make an empty database?  What is the logic behind this behavior?**

**2. Is naming it "sammy" as ridiculous as it seems?  Do users need to be named the same as the databases?  Why or why not?**

It doesn't seem to help to log into the `postgres` identity that installs with postgres:

```
myname@myname:~/Dropbox/working_directory$ sudo -i -u postgres
[sudo] password for myname: 
postgres@myname:~$ pwd
/var/lib/postgresql
postgres@myname:~$ cd /home
postgres@myname:/home$ cd /home/myname/
-bash: cd: /home/myname/: Permission denied
```

OK, that didn't work.  Now, go back to myname@myname:

```
postgres@myname:/home$ sudo -i -u myname
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
postgres@myname:/home$
```

This is where I start swearing.

**3.  How does one get out of the postgres identity?  Besides closing the terminal and opening another one?**

Comment: try typing `psql` with your user `myname`

Answer (score 1):

You are confused on several levels.

1. The message

   ```
   could not change directory to "...": Permission denied
   ```

   is *not* from PostgreSQL or the `createuser` and `createdb` commands, but from `sudo`.

   It tells you that after becoming operating system user `postgres`, it cannot run in your current directory, because user `postgres` doesn't have the required file system permissions.

   Processing continues, however (in a different working directory), and the `createuser` and `createdb` commands succeed.
2. `createuser` and `createdb` do not create something in your current working directory, but in the *database directory*.

   This directory belongs to `postgres`, and you probably can find it with

   ```
   echo $PGDATA
   ```

   when you are user `postgres`.

You exit an interactive `sudo` session by typing `exit`, and the name you give to a database is your choice. You would probably not call your production database “sammy”, but then, why not? Just make sure that you use only letters, numbers and underscores and no upper case characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it not make sense to put the database in some directory of my choosing? How do I give that right to postgres? And is there any reason to name databases after users?

Comment: The only reason to name a database after a user is for a tutorial (which you are following). Normally you leave all data in the data directory. If you have good reasons (like you want to distribute data over different file systems, to distribute the load or limit the size), you could use [*tablespaces*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  I have been assuming that it is unreasonable to store user files (like a database) anywhere but the home directory.

Comment: Well, you choose where the data directory will be when you run `initdb` (which your installation procedure probably did for you).